# How do I use the credit card date format mm/yy in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 child: new TextFormField(                             
   maxLength:5,                                        
   controller:                                         
       TextEditingController(text: donation.date),    
   onChanged: (value) {                                
     donation.date = value;                           
   },                                                  
   decoration: InputDecoration(                        
     suffixText: '',                                   
     suffixStyle: TextStyle(                           
       color: Color(0xffde0486),                       
     ),                                                 
     labelText: 'Expiry Date',                         
     border: OutlineInputBorder(),                     
   ),                                                   
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,                 
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,              
   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),              
   autofocus: true,                                    
 ),
```

I have this piece of code for a credit card that I am implementing in **Flutter**. I want to put the mm/yy format on the textfield. When the user has entered the month, the text field should automatically show the '/'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your result using the `onChange` method. You can check the length of the input and insert a '/' into the text if it is 2 i.e. **dd**

1. You need to store the controller in a seperate variable, because we want to use it later for inserting '/':

```dart
var _controller = new TextEditingController(text: donation.date);
```

2. Add this `_controller` and `onChange` callback to your `TextFormField`:

```dart
TextFormField(                                     
  controller: _controller, //<-- Add controller here
   onChanged: (value) {
     if(value.length == 2) _controller.text += "/"; //<-- Automatically show a '/' after dd
     donation.date = value;                     
   },
   ...                                    
 ),
```

Comment: This one fucks up when you try and delete the input. It won't delete the '/'. It will just keep on adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try this package [flutter_multi_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter) to format the Expiration Date field as well as the credit card number field.

Comment: Easiest solution, even though it has much more stuff than you actually need

Answer (score 0):

Update !
I just found a package: **flutter_masked_text2** that can help you solve the problem!

```
var controller = new MaskedTextController(mask: '00/00');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best but it helps me.

```dart
final myController = TextEditingController();

late String? tmpValue;

...

_cursor();
TextInputField(
  controller: myController,
  onChanged: (value) {
    // check input is number or /
    if (RegExp(r'[^\d/]').hasMatch(value)) {
      return;
    }

    String cardNumber = value;
    bool isDash = (tmpValue ?? '').isEmpty
        ? true
        : (tmpValue ?? '').substring((tmpValue ?? '').length - 1) == '/';

    bool isBackSpace = ((tmpValue ?? '').length - value.length) == 1;

    // check backspace
    if (isDash && isBackSpace) {
      cardNumber = cardNumber.isEmpty
          ? cardNumber
          : cardNumber.substring(0, cardNumber.length - 1);
    }

    // check add /
    bool isRemoveDash = cardNumber.length >= 5;
    String addLine = cardNumber
        .replaceAll('/', '')
        .replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'.{2}'), (match) => '${match.group(0)}/');
    if (isRemoveDash) {
      addLine = addLine.substring(0, addLine.length - 1);
    }

    tmpValue = addLine;
  },
)

...


_cursor() {
  var cursorPos = myController.selection.base.offset;
  myController.text = tmpValue;
  // over string range
  bool isOver = myController.text.length < cursorPos;

  // last is /
  bool isLast = myController.text.isEmpty
      ? true
      : myController.text.substring(myController.text.length - 1) == '/';
  isOver = isOver || isLast;

  myController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(
      offset: isOver ? myController.text.length : cursorPos);
}

...

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  myController.dispose();
}
```

The `inputFormatters` are not set because the display will become strange.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new Formatter class**

```
class ValidityDateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final String separator;

  ValidityDateFormatter({required this.separator});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    var oldS = oldValue.text;
    var newS = newValue.text;
    var endsWithSeparator = false;

    // if you add text
    if (newS.length > oldS.length) {
      for (var char in separator.characters) {
        if (newS.substring(0, newS.length - 1).endsWith(char)) {
          endsWithSeparator = true;
        }
      }
      print('Ends with separator: $endsWithSeparator, so we will add it with next digit.');

      var clean = newS.replaceAll(separator, '');
      print('CLEAN add: $clean');

      // enter only digits
      var isDigit = int.tryParse(newS.characters.last);
      if (isDigit == null) {
        return oldValue;
      }

      // check that the month is not greater than 12
      if (clean.length == 2) {
        var month = int.parse(clean.substring(0, 2));
        if (month > 12) {
          return oldValue;
        }
      }

      if (!endsWithSeparator && clean.length > 1 && clean.length % 2 == 1) {
        print('object $clean');

        return newValue.copyWith(
          text: newS.substring(0, newS.length - 1) + separator + newS.characters.last,
          selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
            offset: newValue.selection.end + separator.length,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    // if you delete text
    if (newS.length < oldS.length) {
      for (var char in separator.characters) {
        if (oldS.substring(0, oldS.length - 1).endsWith(char)) {
          endsWithSeparator = true;
        }
      }
      print('Ends with separator: $endsWithSeparator, so we removed it');

      var clean = oldS.substring(0, oldS.length - 1).replaceAll(separator, '');
      print('CLEAN remove: $clean');
      if (endsWithSeparator && clean.isNotEmpty && clean.length % 2 == 0) {
        return newValue.copyWith(
          text: newS.substring(0, newS.length - separator.length),
          selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
            offset: newValue.selection.end - separator.length,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Next. Use this formatter

```
        TextFormField(
          initialValue: '',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: commonInputDecoration('', '', null),
          inputFormatters: [
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
            ValidityDateFormatter(separator: "/"), // *Here*
          ],
        ),
```

Thanks to [@Mad World](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73196988/14567366)

Answer (score 0):

Create a formatter class :

```html
class ExpireDateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final String separator;

  ExpireDateFormatter({required this.separator});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue previousValue,
    TextEditingValue nextValue,
  ) {
    var text = nextValue.text;
    if (text.length == 1 && int.parse(text) > 1) {
      // Ensure the first digit (month) is not greater than 1
      text = '0$text$separator';
    } else if (text.length == 2 && int.parse(text) > 12) {
      // Ensure the entered month is valid (not greater than 12)
      text = '12$separator';
    } else if (text.length > 2) {
      text = '${text.substring(0, 2)}$separator${text.substring(2)}';
    }
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: text,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: text.length),
    );
  }
}
```

Use it here:

```html
TextFormField(
  initialValue: '',
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: commonInputDecoration('', '', null),
  inputFormatters: [
    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
    ExpireDateFormatter(separator: "/"), // *Here*
  ],
),
```